# Row command event not firing when binding grid view by wizard in dev express

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

i have bind the grid view with the help of wizard. But, after generating the row command event I can't see it being fired.I know question is asked many time and tried many of them in my code but none of them is worked for me

here is my code-

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2"  KeyFieldName="NodeID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" onrowcommand="ASPxGridView2_RowCommand" >
                                           <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="AlarmAlias" VisibleIndex="0" ReadOnly="True">

                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn  FieldName="asu_SMSNight" VisibleIndex="1" ReadOnly="True"> 

                    </dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>

                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="NodeID" VisibleIndex="2"   Caption="Action">

                     <DataItemTemplate>

                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnAllAlarmDelete" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("NodeID") %>' runat="server" >

                        </dx:ASPxButton>

                    </DataItemTemplate>

                   </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  >

</Columns>


<Settings ShowFilterRow="true"  ShowFilterBar="Hidden" ShowFilterRowMenu="true" ShowFooter="True" ShowGroupedColumns="True" ShowGroupFooter="VisibleAlways" ShowHeaderFilterButton="True" ShowHorizontalScrollBar="False" ShowVerticalScrollBar="True" VerticalScrollableHeight="100" VerticalScrollBarStyle="Virtual" />

<SettingsText EmptyDataRow="Select a category to view alarms" />

</dx:ASPxGridView>



<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DTUConnectionString %>"
                                SelectCommand="AD_FetchAlarmByBuildingCategoryUser" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="BuildingId" SessionField="sessionBuilding"
                                        Type="Int32" />
                                    <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="AlarmCategoryid" SessionField="sessionCategory"
                                        Type="Int32" />
                                    <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="UserId" SessionField="sessionUserid"
                                        Type="Int32" />
                                </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

> i m new to dev express. please help

Comment: Show your code behind for `ASPxGridView2_RowCommand` method. Seems that you need to check `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` property values using if-condition.

Comment: It is solved don't know the exact reason but i closed my vs and open my project again and rebuild than it automatically start working @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved don't know the exact reason but i closed my vs and open my project again and rebuild than it automatically start working